# Python 3 Unit Testing: Assert True When Returned Values are Within Range, and Correct Count

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm having a tough time writing unit tests for the following function:

```
def white_nums():
    """Generate 5 'white ball' numbers between 1 and 69--inclusive, no duplicates"""
    whites = random.sample(range(1, 69 + 1),5)  # Python range stops at y - 1 in range(x, y)
    return(', '.join(map(str, whites)))     # strip non-integer characters, separate numbers with commas
```

My thoughts are that I need to test at least the following:

- that the values returned are within the defined range;
- that the count on the returned values == 5;
- that the values returned are not duplicated;
- that the values returned are striped of non-integer characters, and separated by commas.

I'm fairly new to unit testing specifically, and programming in general, but can't seem to create tests for this function that fail. Could someone provide guidance--with specific tests--to help me understand how to approach this problem?

I've committed myself to learning Python's `unittest` module, and appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify the following point:

- All values are hard-coded so where is the need to tests them afterward ?
  Is this just an idea of what you want and you'll then pass the range_min(1) range_max(69) and white_balls(5) as parameters ?

If you stick with the hard-coded values the first two tests are useless.

Then for the duplicates use set(whites) directly, again no need to test it afterward.

Also except for the comma itself you'll never get a non integer character with this line:

```
whites = random.sample(range(1, 69 + 1),5)
```

But why returning a string of number instead of just a list ?

In conclusion while Unit testing is a very good practice in general it seems unnecessary if you keep the hard-coded values.

This is just a proposition as an example:

```
import unittest
import random

def white_nums(range_min, range_max, balls):
    return set(random.sample(range(range_min, range_max + 1), balls))


class TestWhiteNums(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.range_min = 1
        self.range_max = 69
        self.balls = 5
        self.white_balls = white_nums(self.range_min, self.range_max, self.balls)

    def test_count(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(self.white_balls), self.balls)

    def test_range(self):
        for white_ball in self.white_balls:
            self.assertGreaterEqual(white_ball, self.range_min)
            self.assertLessEqual(white_ball, self.range_max)

    def test_duplicates(self):
       self.assertEqual(self.white_balls, set(self.white_balls))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Of course your setUp() function can be more complex and take values from elsewhere. And in your real code you can directly add the white_balls list to your table I think no need to transform it to a string.

Comment: Well, the larger picture is that the returned values will be inserted in to a table. Truth be told, I'm not clear on what is fair game for unit testing and what is not. Here's [the rest of the program](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/53badd31e4991cc6ba278c9b1d32bee8)

Comment: You don't necessary need to return a string to be able to add it to a table.

Comment: The purpose of: `return(', '.join(map(str, whites)))` is to remove brackets `[ ]` generated by `random.`. This was done for aesthetic purposes, and not out of necessity.

Comment: If so I suggest that you do prettying outside of white_nums function when you generate the table, therefore you'll have a proper separation of concern. The logic part and the presentation part. You can create a function for the later one with all needed transformations of the data returned by all other functions, this one would return or print you table at the end.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. Might I ask: what would a unit test look like for a table in this circumstance?

Comment: It depends of what you want to present exactly. If the table is supposed to only contain string you can iterate on the elements and assert that the type is str.

Comment: I'm going to give the unit test class you proposed a try (with some modifications) and let you know how things turn out.

Comment: OK no problem don't hesitate to share what kind of modifications you had to do to make it work, just out of curiosity.